# PHP - big trouble escaping "\"

Tags: php, escaping

I try to explain my problem with a non-perfect english :)

When i try to send some string (client side) to the server, i see that the HTML Form add the "\" char as escape before some chars (for example with ", ' and \ itself).

But this is a problem : if save it on mysql, before i filter the string using mysql_real_escape_string(), and it considers the escape char added by html as a "char added by the user". But that's not true.

The same when, after I checked the value on server-side and ignore it for some reason, i place them on the  fields. I need to escape the chars again (i do it with addslashes() php function), because if i have $var equal to **hello "world" how are you**, on the input field (as i wrote above) it fails.

So, how can I fix this problem? I think there's a solution :)

Part 2

Now, with magic_quotes i've resolved this problem. Now, if the parameter fails when i check it, i'll save it on a var and put it into the right field. The problem is that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#input1").val("<?= addslashes($name) ?>");
    });
</script>       

<input class="inputReg" maxlength="20" name="name" id="input1" />
```

this code work!!! I put the value (trought JQuery). If i write this :

```
<input class="inputReg" maxlength="20" name="name" value="<?=addslashes($name)?>" id="input1" />
```

it doesnt work. In fact, if i write (for example) the string "hello 'my' name is marco" it add each time 1-2-4-8 the char \ before. Why this? It doesnt works. Any idea? Cheers

Comment: char \ is named **slash**. now you can try to guess what does **addslashes** mean

Comment: i know what addslashes() does. For example (with string hello "marco") input field should looks (directly, or trought JQuery) as <input class="inputReg" maxlength="20" name="name" value="hello \"marco\"" id="input1" />. But when i send it, it should remove the slash. IN fact, using Jquery, it does it.

Comment: input field should **not** looks as `<input class="inputReg" maxlength="20" name="name" value="hello \"marco\""`. (not directly nor trough JQuery)

Comment: Ah ok. So i don't know another method to add an escaped string on a input field. And i don't understand why trought JQuery it works hehe

Comment: because this input field is HTML but JQuery is not.

Comment: So i can do it only with JQuery?

Comment: for jquery you should use jquery escaping function, called json_encode. for HTML you should use HTML escaping function, called - surprise! - htmlspecialchars(). but firstly you have to distinguish json from HTML. it's different matters

Comment: oh yeah! Thanks :) i resolved with <input class="inputReg" maxlength="20" name="name" value="<?=htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES) ?>" id="input1" /> ;) Thanks again man, and sorry if i stressed you hehe

Comment: You should create a second question for your second issue -- the two are unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Make sure this is disabled in your php.ini file:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: Also, if for any reason you cannot turn off magic_quotes due to your hosting config, run all your user input through the strip_slashes function.

Comment: i hope it will turn off...otherwise i need to change somethings like 50-60 php files... :)

Comment: @markzzz don't you have a single config file which being included into these 50-60?

Comment: You can also disable it in htaccess: php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

Comment: Col. Shrapnel : i don't understand what you mean. anyway, i contacted my hosting, and yes, i can change that parameters :) nice one

Comment: ok. edited. It works perfectly :) Now i have a trouble. I've edited the topic. Looks at the end, Part 2 :)

Comment: @markzzz do you have a configuration file for your application? A file which being included into other PHP scripts?

Comment: Uhm...not really. For each page i check my variables, i escape them and i manage with DB. Or maybe i misunderstood what you are meaning as configuration file :)

Comment: @markzzz where do you keep database login and password? in a single file or it's written in every file?

Comment: when i do the login i check the value. If they are correct, i save a parameter in the session. After, i have a sort of "filter" that check (for the protected page) if the session-parameter is setted.

Comment: @markzzz a **database** login and password. but okay. it seems all in vain. it seems it's just impossible to explain you anything. nevermind

Comment: i don't keep login and password on php. They are saved on the database. I just keep a session parameter where i save the nickname of that user. Thanks for your time. I ask sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($string))
```

will (temporarily) fix your problem. Turning off magic_quotes though would be the best option.

Comment: all temporary solutions tends to be a forever ones.

Comment: what? :p was just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet if you aint allowed to edit php.ini:

```
# Disable magic quotes if enabled in the server settings
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   function stripslashes_deep($value) {
      $value = is_array($value) ?
         array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
         stripslashes($value);

      return $value;
   }

   $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
   $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
   $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
   $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Not only for you markzz but for those who Google this question as well.